# Как content script общается с background? (В google расширении)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-app

Не получается подключить content script с background. Не реагирует.

Делал таким образом:

**script.js:**

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage('555555555');
```

**background:**

```
chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request){
    if(request=='555555555')
        console.log('Принято: ', request);
});
```

Что здесь не хватает? Есть ли еще способы общения `background` с `content_script` и наоборот `content_script` c `background`?

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой случай.

- отправляем сообщение в фоновую страницу
- слушаем сообщение в фоновой странице
- отправляем ответ (если нужно)

```js
// content script 

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({method: "getGroup"}, function (response) {
    if (response.status != null) {
        //console.log('ответ пришел')
    }
});

// background script 
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
  //console.log('все сообщения')
  if (request.method === 'getGroup') {
       //console.log('get groop')
       sendResponse({status: 'yes'});
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Такого метода как `chrome.extension.sendMessage` не существует. `sendMessage` и `onMessage` лежат в [`chrome.runtime`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime)!

Answer (score -1):

В контент-скрипте требуется пробрасывать объект типа [Port](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#type-Port):

```
var port = chrome.runtime.connect();
```

В нем открываем слушатель:

```
port.onMessage(\* слушатель событий от background-скрипта *\);
```

В контент-скрипте также доступны объекты document и window - через них меняемся данными со страницей через обычные слушатели. Теперь рассмотрим background-скрипт:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function (port) {
  port.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    // работаем с сообщениями от контент-скрипта
  });

  // и отправляем сообщения в контент-скрипты
  port.postMessage({/* тело сообщения */});
});
```